# Angular 2 subscribe property undefined

Tags: angular

I have to send request to server and response object

```
export class OrderResponse{
    constructor(public OrderStatus: string, public Details: string, public Changes: string, public OrderNum?: number){}
}
```

I try to use it in a function:

```
    this.orderService.createOrder(this.orderService.order).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.orderResponse = res;
            //this.router.navigate(["orders", res.OrderNum]);
            console.log(this.orderResponse);
            console.log(this.orderResponse.OrderNum);
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
```

When I log the full response object it logs success:

```
{"OrderNum":62828,"OrderStatus":"Rejected","Details":null,"Changes":null}
```

But when I try to log the OrderNum property it log undefined. How could it be, that object has property value, but it log undefined?

Comment: Is that the full object that it logs out, or is there another object wrapping it?

Comment: 0mpurdy, I don't understand your question. I have a property OrderResponse type in component. I put response result in this property. When I log full object it's ok and show value. When I try to log property of response object - it's undefined.

Comment: Ok and what does `console.log(Object.keys(this.orderResponse))` show?

Comment: It shows (73) ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72"]

Comment: @OlegVolkov please upvote answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the undefined error. Use

- `skipWhile` operator
- `if(condition)` before assiging

  ```
  this.orderService
      .createOrder(this.orderService.order)
      .skipWhile(data=>return data.length)///////////////
      .subscribe(res => {
          if(res){///////////////
              this.orderResponse = res;
              //this.router.navigate(["orders", res.OrderNum]);
              console.log(this.orderResponse);
              console.log(this.orderResponse.OrderNum);
          }
      },(error => console.log(error));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

From your clarification when I asked what `console.log(Object.keys(this.orderResponse))` showed you said:

> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", ...

This means that the `orderResponse` object is actually an array (of what I presume are orders)

If these are orders then `console.log(this.orderResponse[0].OrderNum)` should give you what you are looking for (for the first result, for other results change 0 to the desired order index of the list).

Comment: And what about `console.log(this.orderResponse[0])`